# Lithp Tranthlator

Tags: code-golf, string

My friend made a lisp translator the other day, that is to say it took a string and converted s=>th and S=>Th. It was quite long and I thought that it could be golfed.

So the task is to make a program/function that takes an input string, translates it in to lisp and outputs the string

**Test case**

```
Sam and Sally like Sheep        Tham and Thally like Thheep
Sally likes sausages            Thally liketh thauthageth
Sally sells seashells           Thally thellth theathhellth
```

Note that it doesn't matter that h gets repeated all the time

This is code golf so shortest answer wins

Comment: I wished everyone would change the **bytes** in their headers to **byteth**.

Comment: May someone show this challenge to Mike Tyson?

Comment: There should be bonus points if the program doesn't use `s` nor `S` anywhere in it.

Comment: @NateDiamond great idea, but too late for that, i'm afraid.

Comment: Thufferin' thuccotathh!

Comment: I think the language names should be made clear. Without the replacement. Some languages contain "th" already, so it's ambiguous. And who's to say that someone won't create a different language actually called "Common Lithp" in the future?

Comment: @mbomb007 I wouldn't worry about it too much. I'm not sure if there is actually a default way to title your answer. Most question I see if they do state how to do it it is normally the same way. As I haven't explain how the answer should be set out, then users are free to title them how they want to. Being a pedant, I didn't even ask for a language, so I could argue against them even writing them. But I do understand your point. I just don't think it is of concern

Comment: A thing that would have made this challenge more interesting would be overall case preservation, e.g. `LOOK OUT A SNAKE!!! -> LOOK OUT A THNAKE!!!`

Comment: @fluffy after writing the question I did realise a case like that would fail, but it is too late to change now

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzleth & Code Golf! That Ith a Good quethtion and thothe help the community a lot!

Answer (score 40):

### Common Lithp, 62

```
(map()(lambda(u)(princ(case u(#\s"th")(#\S"Th")(t u))))(read))
```

First, `(read)` the input (it should be a string).
Strings in CL are sequences so we use `map` to iterate on each character. The first argument to `map` represents the type of the result (e.g. I could build a list from a vector). When it is `nil`, a.k.a. `()`, results are discarded. The function that is mapped to the input simply `princ` (print non-readably) each character, except the ones that should be replaced.

Comment: That language name though.

Comment: @JoeZ. I just replaced the `s` by `th`, like everybody else did: look at those Pyson answers.

Comment: @coredump They're all wrong: it's one-way: `s`->`th`, `S`->`Th`, `th`->`th`, `Th`->`Th`.

Comment: I think thith ith invalid. You want `cathe u(#\s"th")` inthtead.

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan Sure,  `(defmacro cathe (&rest args) \`(case ,@args))`

Comment: umm What is Common lithp

Comment: @Matthew Not sure if you are joking or not, but  **Common Lisp** is a language and **Common Lithp** is a pun based on the question. BTW, when I first read the question, I imagined it was about the programming language.

Comment: Ok lol that makes more sense

Answer (score 17):

## Retina, 9 bytes

```
S
Th
s
th
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=UwpUaApzCnRo&input=U2FtIGFuZCBTYWxseSBsaWtlIFNoZWVwClNhbGx5IGxpa2VzIHNhdXNhZ2VzClNhbGx5IHNlbGxzIHNlYXNoZWxscwpTaGUgc2VsbHMgc2VhIHNoZWxscyBvbiB0aGUgc2VhIHNob3Jl)

The obvious answer.

Answer (score 14):

## JavaThcript ETh6, 38 bytes

At first I went with the obvious solution

```
a=>a.replace(/s/g,'th').replace(/S/g,'Th')
```

But I golfed it down 4 bytes

```
a=>a.replace(/s/gi,b=>b>'r'?'th':'Th')
```

This makes use of the regex `i` flag, which searches for case-insensitive patterns. The good thing about Javascript is that you can specify an anonymous function to handle (regex) replacing.

Try it here

```js
f=
a=>a.replace(/s/gi,b=>b>'r'?'th':'Th')

s.innerHTML = [
    'abScdsefSghsij',
    'Sam and Sally like Sheep',
    'Sally likes sausages',
    'Sally sells seashells'
].map(c=>c + ' => ' + f(c)).join`<br>`
```

```html
<pre id=s>
```

Comment: "E eth thickth"?

Comment: I was thinking in `'Tt'[b>'r']+'h'`, but it is the same length

Comment: You mean 38 byteth

Comment: +1 for TIL that string comparison is done via Code Point Value

Comment: @Upgoat That was my fault sorry.

Comment: ¡ʇɐoƃ 'ıH lolol

Answer (score 11):

#### GNU Sed - 17

```
s/S/Th/g;s/s/th/g
```

The obvious answer.

```
$ sed -e "s/S/Th/g;s/s/th/g"

Sam and Sally like Sheep
Tham and Thally like Thheep

Sally likes sausages
Thally liketh thauthageth

Sally sells seashells
Thally thellth theathhellth
```

Comment: Did you mean GNU Thed? ;)

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“Ss”,“Th“th”y
```

Thhowing off Jelly'th thhiny new tranthlate atom. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcU3PigJ0s4oCcVGjigJx0aOKAnXk&input=&args=J1NhbGx5IGxpa2VzIHNhdXNhZ2VzJw)

Answer (score 8):

## Python 3 - 40 byteth

First golfing!

```
lambda s:s.translate({115:'th',83:'Th'})
```

It uses the `str` module's [translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate) method which accepts a translation table. The translation table is a simple `dict` with keycode as keys and the `str` in place of it as value.

Comment: Welcome to the PP&CG community!

Comment: Can I ask you, why you have 2 separate accounts?

Comment: @Bálint Apparently, he forgot to log into his current account with *only 3* rep, but an experience on [so]. And posted with a new account.

Answer (score 6):

### 05AB1E, <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
's„th:'S„Th:
```

The straight forward answer.

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=J3PigJ50aDonU-KAnlRoOg&input=U2FsbHkgbGlrZXMgc2F1c2FnZXM)

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Adnan

Comment: Isn't this the thtraight forward anthwer rather than the straight forward answer?

Answer (score 6):

## JavaThcript ETh6, 43 byteth

```
s=>s.replace(/s/gi,m=>({s:'th',S:'Th'})[m])
```

### Tetht Thuite:

```js
th=s=>s.replace(/s/gi,m=>({s:'th',S:'Th'})[m])
  
console.log(th('Sam and Sally like Sheep'));
console.log(th('Sally likes sausages'));
console.log(th('Sally sells seashells'));
```

Comment: Confethth: thou only wroteth that tetht thuite for the thake of itth title!

Answer (score 6):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 11 byteth

```
Ís/th
ÍS/Th
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=w41zL3RoCsONUy9UaA&input=U2FtIGFuZCBTYWxseSBsaWtlIFNoZWVwICAgICAgICAKU2FsbHkgbGlrZXMgc2F1c2FnZXMgICAgICAgICAgICAKU2FsbHkgc2VsbHMgc2Vhc2hlbGxz)

V ith a language I made. It'th not finithed, but it'th really good at regekth.

Answer (score 5):

## C, 50 bytes

```
s(c){c=getchar();c+=c-83&95?0:'h\1';s(printf(&c));}
```

Replace `\1` with an actual `\x01` byte.

jimmy23013 saved a byte, and then I saved two more using his approach! Thanks.

Comment: I was about to comment that the `&c` parameter is broken. But it's not, because on a little-endian architecture the second byte of that `int` will be `0x00` and actually terminate the "string"... This is horribly clever, I love it !

Comment: `s(c){c=getchar();c+=c-83&~32?0:26625;s(printf(&c));}`

Comment: You can't push 2 bytes into a `char`. *`'h\1'`*

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ Multi-character constants are implementation defined, bu perfectly valid C.

Answer (score 4):

## Java, <strike>71</strike> 65 bytes

```java
String t(String s){return s.replace("S","Th").replace("s","th");}
```

First attempt at golfing, so why not with Java.

Comment: You can use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`

Comment: Oh, yeah you're right. Thanks! @aditsu

Comment: You can save some bytes by using a lambda expression instead of a function. `s->s.replace("S","Th").replace("s","th")`

Answer (score 4):

## TI-Basic, 126 bytes

```
Input Str1
inString(Str1,"s
While Ans
sub(Str1,1,Ans-1)+"th"+sub(Str1,Ans+1,length(Str1)-Ans->Str1
inString(Str1,"s
End
inString(Str1,"S
While Ans
sub(Str1,1,Ans-1)+"Th"+sub(Str1,Ans+1,length(Str1)-Ans->Str1
inString(Str1,"S
End
Str1
```

Comment: This is wrong. `Str1` never changes, and `Ans` will hold a number at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the note, fixed now. I don't know how I forgot to save `Str1` back again...

Comment: This is still wrong; it errors when the first or last character is S. As I've said before, please test your code before you post it.

Answer (score 4):

## Java, 101 byteth

```
interface a{static void main(String[]A){System.out.print(A[0].replace("S","Th").replace("s","th"));}}
```

Note that this is a complete program unlike [the previous Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83146/53917).

Bonus (has to be fed to the <strike>C preprocessor</strike> THEE preprothethor first):

```
#define interfaith interface
#define thtatic static
#define Thtring String
#define Thythtem System
#define replaith(x,y) replace(x,y)

interfaith a{thtatic void main(Thtring[]A){Thythtem.out.print(A[0].replaith("S","Th").replaith("s","th"));}}
```

Answer (score 4):

## GNU AWK, 31 bytes

Just using `gsub` function to translate lower or upper S via regex and print it afterwards.  Can work with files, or with `stdin` as in this case

```
$ awk '{gsub(/s/,"th");gsub(/S/,"Th")}1' <<< "This is Sparta"                   
Thith ith Thparta
```

Comment: `gsub(/s/,"th")gsub(/S/,"Th")` does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

## 35 Byteth of Julia:

```
s->replace(s,r"s"i,s->"$(s[1]+1)h")
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=Zj1zLT5yZXBsYWNlKHMsciJzImkscy0-IiQoc1sxXSsxKWgiKQoKZm9yIHRlc3QgaW4gWygiU2FtIGFuZCBTYWxseSBsaWtlIFNoZWVwIiwgIlRoYW0gYW5kIFRoYWxseSBsaWtlIFRoaGVlcCIpLAogICAgICAgICAgICAgKCJTYWxseSBsaWtlcyBzYXVzYWdlcyIsICAgICAiVGhhbGx5IGxpa2V0aCB0aGF1dGhhZ2V0aCIpLAogICAgICAgICAgICAgKCJTYWxseSBzZWxscyBzZWFzaGVsbHMiLCAgICAiVGhhbGx5IHRoZWxsdGggdGhlYXRoaGVsbHRoIildCiAgICBwcmludGxuKGYodGVzdFsxXSkgPT0gdGVzdFsyXSkKZW5k&input=) (includes all test cases)

Comment: Hey, don't I know you from somewhere? ;)

Answer (score 4):

## C (GCC), 62 byteth

-10 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat; forgot to use the function argument as the iterator.

-1 more byte thanks to @l4m2 and his very smart recursion trick.

```c
l(char*s){*s&&l(s+!!putchar(*s&31^19?*s:104+!putchar(*s+1)));}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9HIzkjsUirWLNaq1hNLUejWFtRsaC0BCSoARQxNowztLTXKrYyNDDRRpLQNtTU1LSu/Z@bmJmnoclVzaUABTkaSsGJpcWJ6akKOZnFBQrFQJCXmphdCWElZqcqaVpz1f4HAA)

Explanation:

```c
l(char*s)
{
    // If at end of string, do nothing.
    *s&&
        // Else, apply this function to the next character in s ...
        l(s+
            // ... but first, print the current character. If the first
            // five bits of *s equal 19 (which they do for 's' and
            // 'S'), print *s+1 (that is, 't' for 's' and 'T' for 'S')
            // before printing character code 104, which is 'h'.
            // If the first five bits aren't 19, just print *s.
            !!putchar(*s&31^19?*s:104+!putchar(*s+1)));}
```

Alternative 62-byte version, made by l4m2:

```c
l(char*s){*s&&l(s+!!printf(*s&31^19?"%c":*s%5?"Th":"th",*s));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9HIzkjsUirWLNaq1hNLUejWFtRsaAoM68kTQMoYGwYZ2hpr6SarGSlVaxqaq8UkqFkpVSSoaQD1KFpXfs/NzEzT0OTq5pLAQpyNJSCE0uLE9NTFXIyiwsUioEgLzUxuxLCSsxOVdK05qr9DwA)

I'm too lazy to explain that one fully, but it's quite similar to the last one except it uses two nested conditional statements to figure out if it should print the current character, `Th` or `th`. The new `*s%5` check is used to figure out if `*s` is `'S'` or `'s'` (knowing that it's one of those), since the ASCII code of `s` is divisible by 5 but `'S'` is not.

Comment: [62](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9HIzkjsUirWLNaq1hNLUejWFtRsaC0BCSoARQxNowztLTXKrYyNDDRRpLQNtTU1LSu/Z@bmJmnoclVzaUABTkaSsGJpcWJ6akKOZnFBQrFQJCXmphdCWElZqcqaVpz1f4HAA)

Comment: @l4m2 That's very clever, thanks a lot :)

Comment: [Alternative 62](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9HIzkjsUirWLNaq1hNLUejWFtRsaAoM68kTQMoYGwYZ2hpr6SarGSlVaxqaq8UkqFkpVSSoaQD1KFpXfs/NzEzT0OTq5pLAQpyNJSCE0uLE9NTFXIyiwsUioEgLzUxuxLCSsxOVdK05qr9DwA)

Answer (score 3):

### Python3 - 46 bytes

```
lambda s:s.replace("s","th").replace("S","Th")
```

Dropped 4 bytes with the help of [@DenkerAffe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/49110/denkeraffe%20DenkerAffe)!

Comment: Python 3 was the language it was originally written in. My version of his code was 59 bytes, so we'll done!

Comment: `lambda s:s.replace("s","th").replace("S","Th")` is a bit shorter.

Comment: @DenkerAffe Yes it is shorter but to use lambda in this case, you would still need an input and an output to answer the original question.

Comment: @george Community consensus is that functions can use arguments and returns values instead of using stdin/stdout. Have a look at our [defaults for I/O](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/49110). While you can of course override them if you want, it wouldn't make much sense in this particular challenge.

Comment: @DenkerAffe okay that's fine. When I asked the question I mean the output would be an echo or print. But I shall leave it to the defaults. So yes using lambda would be shorter

Answer (score 3):

### CJam, 15 bytes

```
q"sS""thTh"2/er
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%22sS%22%22thTh%222%2Fer&input=Sam%20and%20Sally%20like%20Sheep%0ASally%20likes%20sausages%0ASally%20sells%20seashells)

#### Explanation

```
q      e# Read input.
"sS"   e# Push string.
"thTh" e# Push string.
2/     e# Split into pairs, i.e. ["th" "Th"].
er     e# Transliteration, replaces 's' with 'th' and 'S' with 'Th'.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 36 bytes

```
f 's'="th";f 'S'="Th";f x=[x]
(>>=f)
```

Comment: You don't need the space: `f's'=...`

Comment: Sadly, I do. Haskell names may contain apostrophes. :(

Comment: Oh damn I completely forgot that. I almost never need `Char`s...

Comment: I thought it wath "Hathkell"

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 42 Bytes

if run from a file:

```
<?=strtr($argv[1],["s"=>"th","S"=>"Th"]);
```

Run as:

```
~$ php [file] "This is Silly"
```

Comment: -1 byte: remove the newline at the end

Comment: -8 bytes: remove quotes. -> use `php -d error_reporting=0` to suppress notices.

Answer (score 3):

## Rust, 46 bytes

```
|s:&str|s.replace("s","th").replace("S","Th");
```

[Try it online!](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=cf9cd30c67c57031c74f4c6ed5c5add5&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: @mbomb007. I'm not sure you should edit that.

Comment: I'm making it follow the answering guidelines. I should be able to view a post and know what language it is. Some languages contain "th" already, so it's ambiguous. And who's to say that someone won't create a different language actually called "Rutht" in the future?

Comment: @mbomb007, who's to say someone won't create a different language called "Rust" in the future?

Comment: @msh210 Moot point, because if used the poster will need to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

## Befunge 98, <s>37</s> 49 bytes

Original version :

```
~:"s"- #v_$"ht",>,
_;#-"S":<;$"hT",^
```

---

Terminating edition, as per consensus :

```
~:a-!#@_:"s"-#v_$"ht",>,
_;#-"S":      <;$"hT",^
```

This leaves a big honking hole in the code grid that I'm not very happy about. I'll look into that when I have the time.
The 49th byte is a space at the end of the second line, included to have a rectangular grid, required to prevent ccbi (and probably other interpreters) from bugging out and printing an infinite line of "Th"s.

Answer (score 3):

## Emacth Lithp, 61 byteth

```
(lambda(s)(replace-regexp-in-string"[Ss]\\(\\w*\\)""th\\1"s))
```

Emacs Lisp tries to be smart when replacing text, but that smartness breaks when the replaced string only takes up one space, i.e. the capital letter S. To prevent this from converting "Sam and Sally" to "THam and THally", the whole word is matched instead. However, this also handles "SAM and Sally" in the way that one would want, i.e. producing "THAM and Thally".

Answer (score 3):

## x86 machine code, 19 bytes

In hex:

```
86ac3c5374043c73750440aab068aa84c075eec3
```

Input: `ESI`: input string, `EDI`: output buffer.

Disassembly:

```
_loop:
0:  ac          lodsb       
1:  3c 53       cmp al,'S'  
3:  74 04       je _th      
5:  3c 73       cmp al,'s'  
7:  75 04       jne _nth    
_th:
9:  40          inc eax     ;[Ss]->[Tt]
a:  aa          stosb       
b:  b0 68       mov al,'h'  
_nth:
d:  aa          stosb       
e:  84 c0       test al,al  
10: 75 ee       jnz _loop   
12: c3          ret
```

Comment: You can use `test al, 'S'` to check both at once

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 11 bytes

```
ƛ⇩\s=[‛th$•
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwixpvih6lcXHM9W+KAm3RoJOKAoiIsIiIsIlNhbGx5IGxpa2VzIHNhdXNhZ2VzIl0=)

<s>I wath hoping I could find thomething lethth trivial than jutht replacing the letter with the combo but I couldn't.</s> Lookth like I did.

### Explained

```
ƛ⇩\s=[‛th$•
ƛ             # To each character:
 ⇩\s=[        #   if char.lower == "s":
      ‛th$•   #     "th" with the capitalisation of the character
```

Answer (score 2):

### **C# 6.0 - 58 bytes**

```
string f(string s)=>s.Replace("s","th").Replace("S","Th");
```

Takes the input string as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 14 bytes

```
::z\s"th"\S"Th
```

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3A%3Az%5Cs%22th%22%5CS%22Th&input=Sally+sells+seashells&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=Sam+and+Sally+like+Sheep%0ASally+likes+sausages%0ASally+sells+seashells+&debug=0)

Thanks to @LeakyNun for spotting a typo!

Comment: So the language is "Pys"? :P

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 17 bytes

```
115'th'YX83'Th'YX
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MTE1J3RoJ1lYODMnVGgnWVg&input=J1NhbSBhbmQgU2FsbHkgbGlrZSBTaGVlcCc)

#### Explanation

```
115    % 's' (ASCII)
'th'   % String 'th'
YX     % Regex replacement
83     % 'S' (ASCII)
'Th'   % String 'Th'
YX     % Regex replacement
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 53 bytes

```
def l(s):return s.replace("s","th").replace("S","Th")
```

Usage:

```
>> l('Sam and Sally like Sheep')

Tham and Thally like Thheep
```

Comment: -7 bytes: `lambda s:s.replace("s","th").replace("S","Th")` Usage: `(lambda s:s.replace("s","th").replace("S","Th"))(s)`

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ Well, that's identical to TuukkaX's answer (which was posted before mine), so...

Comment: There's no reason to post another answer then.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ I didn't notice his when I posted mine.

Comment: You can delete your answer once you notice there is a shorter one posted before yours.

Answer (score 2):

## GameMaker Language, 74 bytes

```
return string_replace_all(string_replace_all(argument0,'s','th'),'S','Th')
```

Answer (score 2):

### Matlab, 39 byteth

A straitforward approach:

```
@(t)strrep(strrep(t,'s','th'),'S','Th')
```

Answer (score 2):

## [s-lang](http://dgrissom.com/s-lang/index.html), <del>16</del> <del>15</del> 8 bytes (non-competing)

*Saved one byte because s-lang no longer requires last argument bracket*

*Saved seven bytes because of `!` paramater*

#### [Try it online!](http://dgrissom.com/s-lang/index.html?t![s][th)

```
t![s][th
```

s-lang (or, th-lang) is a string manipulation language I am working on for fun.
I am still optimizing argument brackets...

### Explantion

- `t` replace function with search argument and replace argument.
- `!` "preserve case" parameter
- `[s]` the first search argument (searches for the character "s")
- `[th` the first replace argument (now this will replace each "s" with a "th"). End bracket is omitted because it is unnecessary.

Comment: Doesn't `p` parameter need +1 byte?

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ Oh.. it is now "!" instead of "!". I'll fix that

Answer (score 2):

## Brainfuck, 235 byteth

(Newlines included only for readability)

```
,[[>+>+>+<<<-]>>>>-[>+<---]>--[-<<->>]+<<[>>-<<[-]]>>[>-[--->+<]>-.[---->+++++<]>-.<<<-]>>>>
[-]<[>+<[-]]+>[<->-]<[<<<<<-[>++<+++++++++]>+[-<<->>]+<<[>>-<<[-]]>>[>--------[-->+++<]>.---
---------.>]<>[-]<[>+<[-]]+>[<->-]<[<<.>]]>>>>>>>,]
```

Requires 8-bit cells, and 0 on EOF. [Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=LFtbPis-Kz4rPDw8LV0-Pj4-LVs-KzwtLS1dPi0tWy08PC0-Pl0rPDxbPj4tPDxbLV1dPj5bPi1bLS0tPis8XT4tLlstLS0tPisrKysrPF0-LS48PDwtXT4-Pj5bLV08Wz4rPFstXV0rPls8LT4tXTxbPDw8PDwtWz4rKzwrKysrKysrKytdPitbLTw8LT4-XSs8PFs-Pi08PFstXV0-Pls-LS0tLS0tLS1bLS0-KysrPF0-Li0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS4-XTw-Wy1dPFs-KzxbLV1dKz5bPC0-LV08Wzw8Lj5dXT4-Pj4-Pj4sXQ&input=WW91IHNlZSwgeW91bmcgc2FsbHksIHRoYXQgbm90IGFsbCBsYW5nYXVnZXMgYXJlIG1hZGUgZXF1YWwuIFNvbWUgYXJlIHN0dXBpZCwgc29tZSBhcmUgYmVhdXRpZnVsLiBTdGlsbCwgeW91IHNob3VsZCBrbm93IHRoYXQgeW91IGRvbid0IHdhbnQgdG8gbWVzcyBhcm91bmQgd2l0aCBicmFpbmZ1Y2suIE5vIHNpcmVlLg) I thought I could golf tt using some "if = s OR = S" wizardry, but it turns out that this just confounds the system.

### Readable

```
,
[
 [>+>+>+<<<-]>>>
 >-[>+<---]>--
 [-<<->>]+<<[>>-<<[-]]>>
 [ if char = "S"
  >-[--->+<]>-.[---->+++++<]>-.<<<-  output Th
 ]
 >>>

 >[-]
 <[>+<[-]]+
 >[<->-]<    logical negation

 [ else
  <<<<<
  -[>++<+++++++++]>+
  [-<<->>]+<<[>>-<<[-]]>>

   [ if char = "s"
    >--------[-->+++<]>.------------.>  output th
   ]

  <

  >[-]
  <[>+<[-]]+
  >[<->-]<    logical negation

  [<<.>] otherwise output and move to zero cell
 ]
 >>>>>>> we're going to move over some so we can use new cells
 , take more input
]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javathcript, 27 Byteth

```
b=a=>a.replace(/s/gi,'th');
```

Although it is case insensitive it is the smallest JS version so far :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>30</s> 29 byteth

```
$=>[translate&#[S:"Th"s:'th]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?g3IOgW)

Answer (score 2):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), 18 byteth

```
s:
{S,s}=>{Th,th}
```

Answer (score 1):

## <s>SpecBAS</s> ThpecBATh - 53 bytes

```
1 INPUT a$: ?REPLACE$(REPLACE$(a$,"S","Th"),"s","th")
```

Answer (score 1):

### Matlab, 38 <del>42</del> bytes

```
@(t)regexprep(t,{'s','S'},{'th','Th'})
```

Shout out to @LuisMendo for the tip about cell arrays!

For `'Miss Sissy'` yields `ans = Mithth Thiththy`.

Comment: I think straightforward approach is shorter: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83190/55372

Comment: You can use a single call to `regexprep` with cell arrays: `@(t)regexprep(t,{'s' 'S'},{'th' 'Th'})`, 38 bytes

Comment: @LuisMendo I had had problems using cell arrays in regexprep before, but they seem to have straightened that out. Edited!

Answer (score 1):

### Thue, Full program: 27 byteth, function: 13 byteth

```
s::=th
S::=Th
```

<s>Thince Thue can read input, a correct input routine will be too long. Tho i potht it ath a "function"</s>

EDIT: I have forgotten, Thue read lineth from thtdin, not characterth

Tho, here ith a full program:

```
s::=th
S::=Th
I::=:::
::=
I
```

Comment: Is the language Thue or Sue?

Comment: @DerpfacePython The tranthformationth are only `s => th` and `S => Th`, tho it'th Thue.

Comment: Ah, I underthtand now. Thankth!

Answer (score 1):

## PowerThhell, 41 bytes

```
$args.replace('S','Th').replace('s','th')
```

I can't beat this simple approach; there is a string.translate buried in XPath and there are `map` style approaches in the Linq library - but they're wordy. Can't easily do a dictionary lookup per character because PS is case insensitive and thinks 's' and 'S' are duplicate keys.

Best novelty alternative so far:

```
$OFS='Th';''+$args.split('S')-replace's','th'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 18 byteth

The obviouth anthwer; I don't thee anything thhorter. 17 byteth, pluth 1 for `-pe` inthtead of `-e`.

```
s/s/th/g;s/S/Th/g
```

I wathn't thure whether, tho ath to follow the thandard for anthwerth of thith quethtion, I thhould lithpify my code ath well ath my prothe. Jutht in cathe, here'th the lithpy verthion:

```
th/th/th/g;th/Th/Th/g
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 38 bytes

```
load'strings'
rplc&('s';'th';'S';'Th')
```

In J, `rplc` is the string replace verb in the `strings` addon, and it takes a list of boxes where each pair `[x, y]` represents the string `x` to be replaced with `y`.

### Usage

```
   f =: rplc&('s';'th';'S';'Th')
   f 'Sam and Sally like Sheep'
Tham and Thally like Thheep
   f 'Sally likes sausages'
Thally liketh thauthageth
   f 'Sally sells seashells'
Thally thellth theathhellth
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 101 bytes

Note this is a complete C program, unlike [the previous C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83141/55529).

It takes the first command line argument as input. Compile w/ `gcc` and run `./a.out "Sally sells seashells"`

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(int d,char**c){for(d=**++c;d;putchar(d&223^83?d:d+(*0[c]--=104,1)),d=*++*c);}
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome  to PPCG!

Comment: Erm, whether the program is complete doesn't matter. On PPCG we accept *both* full programs *and* functions.

Answer (score 1):

### C, 69 byteth

Reads from `stdin`, writes to `stdout`. Nothing terrific, but somebody had to do it!

```
c;main(){while((c=getchar())>0)printf(c-'s'?c-'S'?"%c":"Th":"th",c);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 47 bytes

Without using the `strings` library.

```
[:;(]`('h',~[:u:1+3&u:)@.([:+/'sS'-:"0]))&.>@;/
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thilicon](http://github.com/m654z/Silicon), 13 byteth

```
i`s|th``S|Th`
```

Pretty simple. `i` to get input, and the rest of it is replacing stuff. Output is implicit.

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 87 bytes

```go
import."strings"
func f(s string)string{R:=ReplaceAll
return R(R(s,"s","th"),"S","Th")}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY9BSsVAEET3c4qmVxmIruXDX3gDyXxwISJNnEnC70zC9GQhn9zBvZsgeAlv4m3smKirKmrxqurtvRmWz5HqMzUeeuqiMV0_DilfY-gzfkw5XN183f9mklMXG0ETplhDKAS2xG5yqQ7Hyo9Mtb9lNsnnKUWoiqqQEgVLzC3aEp26k7p5x7_-0Nb2wsLFODgc4eFxR6KjHig-gyPmF-Du7MG13o8K-Y90CE2iJ-QvFs-ssSdpV4ezCUOCp1JWfKKoh5223WlL5qgL1z_Wmtnsu5Zl028)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 16 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 13.17 bytes

```
's"th"AR'S"Th"AR
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhYb1IuVSjKUHIPUg5VCQDREGCq7YGtwYk5OpUJxak5OMZBMLM4AsSCSAA)

Obviouth anthwer.

##### Explanation

```
's"th"AR'S"Th"AR  # Implicit input
's                # Character 's'
  "th"            # String "th"
      AR          # Replace
        'S        # Character 'S'
          "Th"    # String "Th"
              AR  # Replace
                  # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
`Ss"Thth"½Ṇ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run?code=%60Ss%22Thth%22%C2%BD%E1%B9%86&input=Sally%20likes%20sausages&flags=)

##### Explanation

```python
`Ss"Thth"½Ṇ  # Implicit input
`Ss          # Push "Ss"
   "Thth"    # Push "Thth"
         ½   # Halve it
          Ṇ  # Transliterate
             # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 18 bytes

```
"Th"/"S"\"th"/"s"\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJx9j8FqwzAMhu9+CmF22A6r2XYpyWOkt7ZQkSpRiBtnkQIJY3v2OU27FZZOYPiln8/wFYndsHU2szurUxC7M0aTj4ft+NUlBQAM6SHU6eOhwMqnQzqm3dP+0+jWZngCbI6Qofcj+KomyJiotWn889LF8FNu+NzuZ/Z6FhDsBUuSmbvelUEZ+/jKmG8pIe8jRSg8pV9Mp/3MESrPSwSNM6zaSuJcHo5UBl+sRDGvacgZm5JWeTi5955Eq9CIW7+9vK6dr5TbZ+2wUfaooTPmnjBc5h9rsyQMN3PX3CxK/yWX5L8BpVmhSg==)

- `"s"\` split (implicit) input on `"s"`s
- `"th"/` join with `"th"`
- `"S"\` split on `"S"`s
- `"Th"/` join with `"Th"`

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 14 byteth

```
\s"th":\S"Th":
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%5Cs%22th%22%3A%5CS%22Th%22%3A&input=This+answer+is+very+simple+and+boring.)

Thith anthwer ith very thimple and boring.

Answer (score 0):

### TCC - 28 bytes

```
=SO;i;{'s';'th';{'S';'Th';SO
```

[Try it online!](https://www.ccode.gq/projects/tcc.html?code=%3DSO%3Bi%3B%7B%27s%27%3B%27th%27%3B%7B%27S%27%3B%27Th%27%3BSO&input=Sam%20and%20Sally%20like%20Sheep)

Explanation:

```
=SO;i;                       - Load input (i) into SO (string operations)
      {'s';'th';             - Replace 's' with 'th' in SO
                {'S';'Th';   - Replace 'S' with 'Th' in SO
                          SO - Implicit print of SO
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 50 byteth

```
\&Th&th|Ig0Ig0I^P3[g["S"b1]["s"b2][^"S"[^"s"b]]>]`
```

[Try it Online!](http://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%5C%26Th%26th%7CIg0Ig0I%5EP3%5Bg%5B%22S%22b1%5D%5B%22s%22b2%5D%5B%5E%22S%22%5B%5E%22s%22b%5D%5D%3E%5D%60&inputs=Sally%20sells%20seashells)

## Explanation

```
\&Th&th|                          pass [(user input), "Th", "th"] to program
        I                         place list items in consecutive memory slots, move pointer to next free slot
         g0                       get item 0 (user input)
           I                      place list items in consecutive memory slots, move pointer to next free slot
            g0                    get item 0 (user input)
              I^                  set top of stack to the length of this item
                P3                move the pointer to slot 3

[ ... ]`                          loop n times, where n is the top of the stack
 
g                                 get the value at the pointer
 ["S"  ]                          if the value is "S",
     b1                           add the item in storage at pointer 1 ("Th") to print buffer
        ["s"  ]                   if the value is "s",
            b2                    add the item in storage at pointer 2 ("th") to print buffer
               [^"S"       ]      if the value is not "S",
                    [^"s" ]       if the value is not "s",
                         b        add the item to the print buffer
                            >     move the pointer right
                                  the buffer is printed implicitly
```

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 50 byteth

Here's an alternative approach using ASCII values that turned out to be the same byte count:

```
\&Th&th|Ig0Ig0I^P3[gn[83b1][115b2][^83[^115gb]]>]`
```

[Try it Online!](http://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%5C%26Th%26th%7CIg0Ig0I%5EP3%5Bgn%5B83b1%5D%5B115b2%5D%5B%5E83%5B%5E115gb%5D%5D%3E%5D%60&inputs=Sally%20sells%20seashells)

Answer (score 0):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 23 bytes

```
*.trans(<s S>=><th Th>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcvBCsIwEIThVxlKMVrEoxebvES8l4VujLitJVsPofjssT0Ub8M3/BMnuZYh4xBgS3OZE416bBXeWdfOEffoTuUGpYyq7mAdloC6@1YI7wTjaQCNPTyJZMjzxfCReTLn7dtN1/6j9GD9u7LI6kwat2XKDw)

Just calls the built-in string `trans`late function.

Answer (score 0):

## [Racketh](https://racket-lang.org) -- 58 bytes

```rkt
#!racket
(regexp-replaces(read-line)'(["s""th"]["S""Th"]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCsIwEEX3nmIcFzaQegB3gieoIkhxEduhLaaZMpOAnj7Gunvvwf/iuhfFnHdbWWlTCQ30XmqhxbuOtLjraz8FMvuqRUWMIz5avCBeCxiT85mcQLPOj9CwkoITAqHewm1iT/Efnj6RhTun1eYPaAo6lmcLp9D/wswc/DSMESLz4Qs)

---

### Explanation

On line one we have the required language expression for Racket.

On line two we pass user input to a function that uses regular expressions to replace certain characters ("s" becomes "th" and "S" becomes "Th").

```rkt
#lang racket
(regexp-replaces (read-line) '(["s" "th"] ["S" "Th"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 17 bytes

```
s/s/th/g
s/S/Th/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcjBCYAwDAXQe6fIBhkmLhDopxWjFL4enD5WELw9HlEzqdSzaytU02Ui03wXP6qYR9wS6waxDozyB4V@0Rv4JRExE87@6gE)

Pretty thimple. It'th what thed it made for.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>11</s> 10 [byteth](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
„sS„thD™‚‡
```

Originally thuggethted ath a golf for [the exithting 05AB1E anthwer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83138/52210), but I decided to potht it ath a theparated anthwer after there wath no rethpondth for halve a year. :)

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcO84mAgUZLh8qhl0aOGWY8aFv7/r6SkFJyYq5CYl6IQnJiTU6mQk5mdqhCckZpawIUQKFYoTiwtTkxPLYYKFqfm5AAFUxOLM0AsoCkA)

**Explanation:**

```python
„sS         # Push string "sS"
   „th      # Push string "th"
      D     # Duplicate it
       ™    # Titlecase the copy
        ‚   # Pair the two together: ["th","Th"]
         ‡  # Transliterate all "s" to "th" and "S" to "Th" in the (implicit) input
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

PTh: Altho workth in [2thable](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable):
[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MypOTMpJ/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3l/0cN84qDgURJhsujlkWPGmY9alj4X@d/cGKuQmJeikJwYk5OpUJOZnaqQnBGamoBF0KgWKE4sbQ4MT21GCpYnJqTAxRMTSzOALEA) (Hello. Table for two, pleathe. ;p)

Answer (score 0):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 183 byteth

```
-[>+<---]>-->>>+[->-[<]>--]>-<<<+[-->++[<]>-]>+<<,[[-<+<+<+>>>]>>[<<+<->>>-]<<[->>+<<]+<[[-]>-<<<<[->>->+<<<]>>>[-<<<+>>>]+<[<.>>-]>[<<+.>>->>>>.<<<]]>[<<<+.>>>->>>.<<]<<<[-]<[-]>>>,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1dT8IwFIbv9yt67SgXagImTRMVBvgBSoeoSy8GlK2uDFw3YP75eU5nYk6avn3ynLerItb5tlpnTUMj7jNKqeSUcs79iHIaMXzBYYwBoNz3HZKgsk4UUebjgC45j8BhuEolY7CNjvQZWG2BYxQpVIDuSnEVHNbFNVeBCSjvoueQYw4Ck65I4gHQkU0Tr9YbtU1S/ZWZXb4/fBe2rI6nc/1ze3c/GAaj8eTh8el5Ont5nYtw8bZ8//gkIq5snChPxDsS5xt4G1MTozNFRKrUwfsHlthWtn/QKmMAqtimmDxB2rHteCItVOZd3fTXveu617@8mCejYCnGg8Vk7M1yRcLTnoQgKRLsq4IE@gi/6jMR6qhyMtRJWpKpRlHl3tA4Gp6UAS1MdVEqeONmG/TW3VDQ3qi75IowYJcLUJKX9S8)

### Explanation

```
[
* https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants
* https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_algorithms
*
* Cell #    Name    Explanation
* 0         tc0     Unused except right at the start for making 83 ('S')
* 1         tc1     Stores 'S'
* 2         tc1p5   Temp cell & used for outputting input char
* 3         tc2     Temp cell & holds input char - 'S' 
* 4         tc3     Temp cell & holds input char - 's'
* 5         tc4     Temp cell & input initially starts here
* 6         tc4p5   Temp cell
* 7         tc5     Stores 's'
* 8         tc6     Stores 'h'
*
* Algorithm:
*   initialization
*
*   while (ch = input()) {
*       if ((ch - 's') != 0) {
*           if ((ch - 'S') != 0) {
*               output(ch)
*           } else {
*               output(ch + 1)
*               output('h')
*           }
*       } else {
*           output(ch + 1)
*           output('h')
*       }
*   }
]

-[>+<---]>-- make 83 ('S') on tc1 end tc1

>> make space for tc1p5 and tc4p5

>+[->-[<]>--]>- make 104 ('h') on tc6 end tc6
<<<+[-->++[<]>-]>+ make 115 ('s') on tc5 end tc5

<<,[ tc4 begin input loop

handling:
    'S': output Th
    's': output th
    else: output char

[-<+<+<+>>>] copy tc4 to tc3 tc2 tc1p5 end tc4

>> tc5 s
[<<+<->>>-] move tc5 to tc4 and sub from tc3 end tc5
<<[->>+<<] tc4 move back to tc5 end tc4

+ tc4 is 1
<[
    tc3 is not 's'
    [-] zero tc3 
    >-< tc4 to zero   

    <<< tc1
    [->>->+<<<] tc1 to sub tc2 and add tc3 end tc1
    >>>[-<<<+>>>] tc3 to tc1 end tc3
    
    + tc3 one
    <[
        tc2 is not 'S'
        <. output tc1p5
        
        > tc2
        >-
    ]>
    [<
        tc2 is 'S'
        <+. tc1p5 output 'T'
        >>->>>>. tc6 output 'h' and dec tc3 along the way

        <<< tc4
    ] end tc4

]>
[< tc3 and tc3 is 's'
    <<+. tc1p5 make 't' output
    >>>->>>. tc6 output 'h' and dec tc4 along the way
    << tc4p5
] end tc4p5  tc4 0 tc4p5 0  

<<<[-] tc2 zero
<[-] tc1p5 zero

>>> tc4

,] end tc4
```