# Print the ASCII printable character set

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

**Challenge:** Print the **entire** printable ASCII charset (not just a range!) in order.

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

**Rules:** *read closely*

- No other characters allowed in the output.
- Program/function does not accept input.
- Try not to hardcode/embed the output.
- This is code golf, shortest answer wins.

Comment: Well they are a couple main things about this challenge that are why it's getting downvoted. A) the community really [doesn't like](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8058/40695) it when you ban golfing language (whether or not I agree with this is a different matter) B) it's rather simple but I wouldn't say it's exactly _trivial_ (kinda on the edge). Also saying "Try not to ..." usually isn't a good sign because it's not actually enforcing it (because it's hard to enforce this objectively), and it might mean your challenge may not be found that interesting (therefore getting downvotes).

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret *try not to hardcode the output* here. For a constant output challenge, that's the only way...

Comment: @Dennis I meant something like: ```echo " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"```

Comment: Do we have to *print* the output from a function or is returning a string acceptable?

Comment: Are built-ins accepted or not? The rule about hardcoding is not clear on that. The MATL answer form @Suever seems to use built-in that contains the printable ASCII.

Comment: Does "no other characters" include embedded newlines?

Comment: :( unfortunately the Brainfuck code `+[+.]` (5 bytes) doesn't count as it fails the first rule...

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of that challenge! Programs there had to accept input and print only part of the table. This challenge is easier and different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## MATL, 3 bytes

```
6Y2
```

[**Try it Online**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=Nlky&input=)

And for the sake of a non-built-in (7 bytes)

```
32:127c
```

Comment: Non-builtin: `'~':`.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Unfortunately that didn't work until [18.5.0](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/18.5.0). [Here's](https://matl.suever.net/?code=%27~%27%3A&inputs=&version=18.4.0) what it looked like at the time of this challenge.

Answer (score 18):

## Brainfuck, <s>30</s> 27 bytes

```
+[[>++<<+>-]>]<<<++[<.+>++]
```

[Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=K1tbPisrPDwrPi1dPl08PDwrK1s8Lis-Kytd&input=)

#### How it works

`+` changes the initial cell to **1**. After this step, we enter the following, nested loop.

```
[        While the current cell is non-zero:
  [        While the current cell (C) is non-zero:
    >++      Increment the cell to C's right twice.
    <<+      Increment the cell to C's left.
    >-       Decrement C.
  ]
  >        Advance to the cell to C's right.
]
```

This computes consecutive powers of **2** until the the value **256 = 0 (mod 256)** is reached. When the outer loop finishes, the tape is in the following state.

```
                                     v
001 002 004 008 016 032 064 128 000 000 000
```

`<<<++` retrocedes three cells and increments twice, leaving the tape as follows.

```
                         v
001 002 004 008 016 032 066 128 000 000 000
```

Now we're ready to print the actual output. As a stop condition, we increment the cell above twice each time we print and increment the cell to its left. Since **66 + 95 × 2 = 256 = 0 (mod 256)**, we stop after printing all **95** printable ASCII characters. We achieve this as follows.

```
[      While the current cell (C) is non-zero:
  <      Retrocede to the cell to C's left.
  .+     Print its content and increment.
  >++    Increment C twice.
]
```

Comment: with Dennis brainfuck outgolfs procedual programming languages!

Comment: @Dennis - You may want to add a leading `>`. Your implementation runs off the tape to the left, which few interpreters support.

Comment: @owacoder On PPCG, languages are defined by their implementations. As long as there is *one* interpreter that behaves as desired (and the one on Try it Online! does), it's considered valid.

Comment: @owacoder Well actually a lot of interpreters support negative tape indices nowadays

Answer (score 7):

## Brainfuck, <s>40</s> 39 bytes

```
++++[->++++[->++>++++++<<]<]>>>-[-<.+>]
```

[Try it online.](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=KysrK1stPisrKytbLT4rKz4rKysrKys8PF08XT4-Pi1bLTwuKz5d&input=)

### Explanation

```
++++[->++++[->++>++++++<<]<]
```

The nested loops basically mean you multiply the number of plusses together, so 4 × 4 × 2 = 32 in one cell and 4 × 4 × 6 = 96. Here is the tape after running this:

```
00 00 32 96
 ^
```

---

`>>>-` moves the pointer to the fourth cell and decrements it. Now we're done with the setup. 32 is the code for space, the first printable ASCII character. 95 is the number of characters we have to print. Here is the tape now:

```
00 00 32 95
          ^
```

---

`[-<.+>]` runs until the current cell (the fourth one) is zero. It decrements the counter and prints the character and increments it for the next time.

Answer (score 7):

## Cheddar, 29 bytes

```
->(32:126).map((i)->@"i).fuse
```

Range from 32-126, loop over it and get the string at the given char code `@"` and the fuse together (join)

### Cheddar, 7 bytes

```
32@"126
```

Unfortunately this is broken as of the current release but I'm sure you can go back some versions where this works

Comment: eyyy my `@"` operator!

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ it's a very useful operator 10/10

Answer (score 6):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 18 bytes

```
~
{2`
$`
T01`p`_p
```

The leading linefeed is significant.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=Cn4KezJgCiRgClQwMWBwYF9w&input=)

#### Explanation

**Stage 1: Substitution**

```
~
```

We start by replacing the empty (non-existent) input with a single `~`.

**Stage 2: Substitution**

```
{2`
$`
```

The regex of this substitution is still empty, since the `` ` `` separates configuration from regex and `{2` is therefore just the configuration. The `{` indicates that the remaining two stages should be run in a loop until they stop changing the output. The `2` indicates that this specific stage has a limit of `2`, meaning that only the first two matches of the regex will be replaced. Since the regex is empty, that means we get an empty match in front of the string and an empty match after the first character.

This match is replaced with the prefix `` $` `` which refers to everything in front of the match. For the first match, there is nothing in front of it, so this doesn't insert anything, but for the second match, there is the leading character in front of it, which therefore gets duplicated.

**Stage 3: Transliteration**

```
T01`p`_p
```

Here, `T` activates transliteration mode, and `0` and `1` are limits (where `0` just means "don't set this limit"). Together, they mean "transliterate only the first character in the string". The actual transliteration maps from `p` to `_p`. Here, `p` expands to the printable ASCII characters and `_` means "remove" this character, so the expanded lists look like this:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
_ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

That means spaces get removed and all other characters get decremented by one.

To see how the last two stages act together here is the string after each of the first few and last stages:

```
~
~~
}~
}}~
|}~
||}~
{|}~

...

"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
""#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
!!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
  !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Since the state of the string is only checked after every other stage to determine whether to end the loop, and the two stages cancel each other once we reach the leading space (since Stage 2 adds a space and Stage 3 removes it), this terminates the loop and therefore the program.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2.7, 36 bytes:

```
print''.join(map(chr,range(32,127)))
```

Simple enough. A full program that prints out the entire ASCII sequence in order.

Answer (score 4):

## Octave, 13 bytes

```
disp(' ':'~')
```

Try it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/XcdBES).

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 54 bytes

```bash
man ascii|fold -w1|LC_ALL=C sort -u|tr -cd '[:print:]'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzcxTyGxODkzsyYtPydFQbfcsMbHOd7Rx8fWWaE4v6hEQbe0pqRIQTc5RUE92qqgKDOvxCpW/f9/AA)

I like that this uses the ASCII man page (which contains an ASCII table) to extract the characters.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 30 bytes

```python
print bytearray(range(32,127))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EIamyJDWxqCixUqMoMS89VcPYSMfQyFxT8/9/AA)

Answer (score 3):

### Pyth, 5 bytes

```
srd\
```

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=srd%5C%7F&debug=0).

```
 r         range from
  d        space
   \<del>  to the delete character, 0x7F (included literally in the program)
s          sum (concatenate all)
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 54 bytes

```
for(i=32;i<128;i++)console.log(String.fromCharCode(i))
```

Wasted quite a few bytes printing it... Also prints each char on a new line.

Comment: If you start the loop in `31`, you can save one byte removing `i++` and using `String.fromCharCode(++i)`.

Comment: `console.log` can become `alert` if you don't mind clicking through 97 boxes

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 48 bytes

```java
v->{for(char i=31;++i<127;)System.out.print(i);}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY7BDoIwEETvfMUe2xBI0IOHin8gFxIvxsNaQFdLIW1pYgjfXoty2clOJm/mhR6zV/MOUqG1cEbScwJA2rWmQ9lCtb4AfqAGJLus4rmI3pLEYx06klCBhhKCz05zNxgmn2iAyn0h0pSOxe4geP2xru3zYXL5aCKdERdLECtjnO4qMjbUr6iPM1jtYvBxvQHy/wadS6Ynpbb6JXwB)

**Explanation:**

```java
v->{                       // Method with empty unused parameter and no return-type
  for(char i=31;++i<127;)  //  Loop characters from ' ' to '~'
    System.out.print(i);}  //   And print it
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 6 bytes

```
',32>
```

The second byte is a DEL character. [Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=J38sMzI-&input=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 17 bytes

```perl6
print |(' '..'~')
```

```perl6
print chrs ^95+32
```

Answer (score 2):

### C, 40 bytes

```
f(){for(char i=32;i<128;i++)putchar(i);}
```

Comment: New here, but do you have to declare a func? (without the `f(){` is not ok?)

Comment: @RingØ In C, you can't just write code without a function. each submission has to compile or run, so in JS for example it would be ok to not put the f() but it's required for C.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + general Linux utilities, 18

```
jot -s '' -c 95 32
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 3 bytes

```
@Pw
```

`@P` is the string that contains the printable ASCII characters so… yeah, not very interesting.

It's not clear whether OP accepts built-ins or not, and since others have posted answers that use built-ins, I'll use the 3 bytes version until OP clarifies this point.

#### With no built-in, 14 bytes

```
32:126e          Get a number between 32 and 126
       :"~c"w    Format that number to STDOUT as a char code
             \   Backtrack
```

Answer (score 2):

## TSQL, 53 bytes - Vertical solution

```
DECLARE @ int=32x:PRINT char(@)SET @+=1IF @<127GOTO x
```

**[Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/510173/print-the-ascii-printable-character-set)**

## TSQL, <s>75</s> <s>71</s> 68 bytes - Horizontal solution

```
DECLARE @ char(95)=''WHILE 95>LEN(@)SET @=char(126-LEN(@))+@ PRINT @
```

**[Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/510780/print-the-ascii-printable-character-set)**

Comment: this can be executed on any version of sqlserver from this millennium

Comment: `Horisontal`=>`Horizontal` ;)

Comment: The second solution appears to be missing the leading space. You can save 3 bytes by changing `SELECT` to `SET`.

Comment: @BradC you are absolutely right, thanks. Fixed - considering my more complex answers, I can't believe i missed something this obvious.

Comment: Vertical solution isn't valid

Comment: @ASCII-only does it give incorrect result ? It executes fine in the fiddle

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Yeah, but IMO the newlines count as "other characters"

Comment: @ASCII-only I agree. It could very well be interpreted that way, which is why I provided both answers

Comment: Here's a `varchar` version that fixes the leading space, also builds from the left instead of the right: `DECLARE @ varchar(94)=' 'WHILE 94>LEN(@)SET @+=char(LEN(@)+33)PRINT @`

Comment: @BradC I tried with the varchar first. But saved 1 bytes building it from the right

Comment: @t-clausen.dk But I still don't get a leading space from your latest code, looks like all you did was change the `SELECT` to `SET`. If you change both 94s to 95 that seems to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 17 bytes

```
$><<[*' '..?~]*''
```

or

```
print *[*' '..?~]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 1 [byte](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
Ｃ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjIz,v=2)

---

*Without builtin:*

### <s>15</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
９⁵×４－｛⁷⁷＋＋╷ｃ］∑
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjE5JXUyMDc1JUQ3JXVGRjE0JXVGRjBEJXVGRjVCJXUyMDc3JXUyMDc3JXVGRjBCJXVGRjBCJXUyNTc3JXVGRjQzJXVGRjNEJXUyMjEx,v=2)

Comment: :| that's really long without builtin

Comment: @ASCII-only yeah. `⁴⁷⁷＋＋╷` is the shortest way i could find to make the number 95 (Canvas only has literals for 0-9, and predefined variables for 10, Infinity, 256, 13, 64, 11, 12, 16, and 128.)

Comment: lol nvm found a shorter one

Comment: [10 bytes](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=XyV1RkY0MyV1RkY1QiUyMCV1RkY0MyV1RkYwQiV1MjU3NyV1RkY0MyV1RkYzRCV1MjIxMQ__,v=2)

Answer (score 2):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 24 bytes

```
IO.puts Enum.uniq 32..?~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@v/f01@voLSkWME1rzRXrzQvs1DB2EhPz77u/38A)

Prints a trailing newline. If that's not acceptable, it's +1 byte for `write` instead of `puts`.

`uniq` is the cheapest operation I managed to find for converting range to list. As a bonus, here are 4 different programs that all accomplish the task in 27 bytes:

```
IO.puts Enum.to_list 32..?~
IO.puts Enum.into 32..?~,[]
IO.puts Enum.take 32..?~,95
IO.puts for n<-32..?~,do: n
```

Answer (score 2):

#### x86_16 machine code - <strike>21</strike> 15 bytes

-6 bytes, thanks [@anna328p](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53551/anna328p)

```
B8 20 0E        MOV AX, 0E20H
            .LOOP:
CD 10           INT 10H
40              INC AX
3C 7E           CMP AL, 7EH
75 F6           JNE .LOOP
B8 4C00         MOV AX, 4C00H
CD 21           INT 21H
```

Running on DOSBox :

[image]

Comment: Is line 17 needed?

Comment: @anna328p of course, The program will hang if there is no exit function after the loop

Comment: I got it down to 15 bytes: `uCAOzRBAPH91+bhMAM0h` (base64)

Comment: cool ! , thank you

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 7 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Full program.

```apl
' '…'~'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO94L@6gvqjhmXqdeog7n8FMCgAAA)

Do I need to explain?

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) using only keywords with lowercase alphabets only separating each of them only a space, <s>227</s> 129 bytes

```perl
eval q y print chr length xor s qq q while uc le q q q x length q q truncate tie q x length q q foreach q y for q q q x ord q q q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY1LDoAgEEOv0kt4IDKOQkL4jIPi6RExujDdtHltmlj81BrvxiPjRBIXFGQFnsOqFjUKNuTc6WGdZxTqCHmovq07qJRARhnq@M@WKGzIjovuv3mU@fGtXQ)

### How it works

```perl
eval q y
      print chr length
      xor s qq q
   while
      # default variable has spaces only; equibalent to $_
      uc
      # instead of <=126
      le q q q
         # 126==14*9
         x length q q truncate tie q
         x length q q foreach q
# just noticed i could golf the word
y for q q q x ord q q q
```

### Previous: 227 bytes.

```perl
eval q y print chr length xor s qq q while chr length lt chr length q q length length length length length length length length length length length length length length length length length length q y foreach q q q x ord q q q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xY9RCoAgEESvMpfoQGJbCou6m5SdfkskqBP0NQPvfcwUUp7MaHcMwYmiMVX4oGBKaw1oWbFB5KZHiExvxh@zKw/4J/qBJSs5P9YIGrLOo5td)

#### How it works

Using length of default variable to be accumulator.

```perl
eval q y
      # print chr($accumulator)
      print chr length xor
      # increment it
      s qq q
   while
      # instead of <
      chr length lt
      # 127 is unfortunately a prime; any efficient ideas within the restrictions?
      chr length q q length length length length length length length length length length length length length length length length length length q
# $accumulator=32
y foreach q q q x ord q q q
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
kPs5ȯ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=kPs5%C8%AF&inputs=&header=&footer=)

-2 byte thanks to @AaronMiller

Comment: [5 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=kPs5%C8%AF&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: @AaronMiller thanks! Nice trick of slicing ascii characters

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org), 20 bytes

```py
lambda:range(32,127)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fUJSZV6Khrq6XlZ@Zp5GbWKCRnFGko/E/JzE3KSXRqigxLz1Vw9hIx9DIXPO/poYmEPwHAA) Returns a `range` of codepoints.

```py
lambda:range(32,127)  # full program
lambda:               # return function taking no arguments that returns...
       range(  ,   )  # range object of all integers between...
             32       # literal...
       range(  ,   )  # minus 1 and...
                127   # literal
```

Answer (score 1):

## SQL, <s>76</s> 75 bytes

(Microsoft SQL Server 2012+)

```
declare @ int=32;while(@<127)begin;print char(@);set @+=1;end
```

[Demo](http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/510047)

Comment: Not sure outputting on separate lines satisfies the challenge. Also, can save a few bytes with a label/and `GOTO` instead of `while`.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>40</s> <s>30</s> <s>29</s> <s>26</s> 24 bytes

Thanks to Mego, manatwork and Titus for helping me golf this down.

```
<?=join(range(' ','~'));
```

Comment: I think #128 is out of printable ASCII. Anyway, [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) can generate character sequence directly, no need to `chr()` them one by one.

Comment: `range` is inclusive (unlike Python's `range`, which includes the start but not the end), so it should be `range(32,127)`.

Comment: [`join()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)'s first parameter “Defaults to an empty string.” Then you have an unnecessary space after the second `,`.

Comment: Yepp, my explanation officially sucks. :( To translate my previous comment: `join()`'s first parameter is optional.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can replace `echo` with `<?=` and then save a byte.

Comment: @Midnightas: 2 bytes. also drop the blank behind the `echo`

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL](https://dyalog.com/), 11 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```
⎕UCS 31+⍳99
```

`⍳99` integers 1 through 99

`31+` add 31 to them

`⎕UCS` pick those from the Unicode Character Set

Answer (score 1):

## Julia 0.4, 18 bytes

```julia
map(print,' ':'~')
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=bWFwKHByaW50LCcgJzonficp&input=)

If returning a string from a function is acceptable, a further byte can be saved.

```julia
f()=' ':'~'|>join
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 16 bytes

```
putStr[' '..'~']
```

Answer (score 1):

### C#, <s>51</s> <s>45</s> 40 bytes

```
for(char x=' ';x<=128;)Debug.Write(x++);
```

Comment: I think that this doesn't qualify just yet, since it isn't a full program or a function. Also, why do you cast the `x` to a `char` when giving `x` a value?

Comment: Yeah, but there is 2 casts in your code...?

Comment: You can rewrite your `for` to be shorter `()=>{for(int x=31;x<126;)Debug.Write((char)++x);};` (I also use a lambda to be pendatic with PPCG will. Here we use an `Action` instead of a `Func`)

Comment: You can remove your cast by incrementing your char. `()=>for(char x=' ';x<127;)Debug.Write(x++);};`

Comment: Also nice first answer! Feel free to step by the [Tips for code-golfing in C#](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tips-for-code-golfing-in-c?answertab=active#tab-top) page for more tips! I just referenced this post in it ;)

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 5 bytes

```
~KS4>
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%7EKS4%3E)

Pyke's printable variable isn't sorted and it contains tabs and newlines etc... :(

Answer (score 1):

### C - 35 bytes

```
f(i){for(i=31;++i<128;putchar(i));}
```

Call:

```
int main() {
    f();
}
```

<strike>Uses the horrible `int`-as-a-string trick I learnt from [Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83141/30000).</strike> (Will again if OP confirms that a vertical output is OK).

Comment: That only works on little-endian machines though. `putchar(i)` is the same length.

Comment: @owacoder mmh, I had `puts` there originally, but then I changed it because of the newlines and didn't question it further. Thanks!

Comment: `i;f(){for(;++i<96;putchar(i+32));}` also works, and saves a byte.

Comment: [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P00jWbM6Lb9II9nW2Mi6oLQkOSMRyNHW1rRRr1O31rSu/Z@ZV8KVm5iZp1GWn5miyVXNxZmmoWnNVfsfAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 22 bytes

```
32~CharacterRange~126&
```

Pretty simple. `&` creates an anonymous function and `32~CharacterRange~126` outputs a [list of characters](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2216) from 32 () to 126 (`~`). Actually, I'm pretty sure this is optimal this time.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 57 bytes:

Prints individual characters

```
Sub a()
For i = 32 To 126
Debug.Print Chr(i)
Next
End Sub
```

Prints out joined string, **68 bytes**

```
Sub a()
For i = 32 To 126
b = b & Chr(i)
Next
Debug.Print b
End Sub
```

Comment: 27 bytes in VBA Immediate Window: `For i=32To 126:?Chr(i):Next` or, for all one string with no line breaks, 28 bytes: `For i=32To 126:?Chr(i);:Next`

Answer (score 1):

### [**Majc**](https://github.com/lvivtotoro/majc) (formely hashmap), 6 bytes

```
r af
```

The delete character is unprintable so here's the hex code (xxd):

```
0000000: 7220 7f61 660a                           r .af.
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 33 bytes

```
i;f(){++i<96&&putchar(i+31)|f();}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 12 bytes

The  is the Unit Separator character `\x1F` (31)

```
+;T`p`p_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/n0ueS9s6JEG@IKEg/v9/AA)

---

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 18 bytes

Same method as above, but requires some extra bytes for printing and not having a trailing newline.

```
+*\T`p`p_
\`.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fS55LWysmJEG@IKEgnismQY/r/38A)

---

If, like in [Martin's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85123/34718), a trailing newline is acceptable, then this is possible, beating him by 5 bytes:

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 13 bytes

```
+*\T`p`p_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fS55LWysmJEG@IKEg/v9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 9 bytes

```
`_FLss|rH
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/PyHezae4uKbI4/9/AA)

#### How it works

```
`_FLss|rH

`_F...|    Run the following 95 times:
   Lss       Push the loop counter + 32
       rH  Print all the chars in the pushed order and halt
```

Answer (score 1):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 30 bytes

```fs
Seq.iter(printf"%c")[' '..'~']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv3/Pzi1UC@zJLVIo6AoM68kTUk1WUkzWl1BXU9PvU499v9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 55 bytes

```
set i 31
time {puts -nonewline [format %c [incr i]]} 95
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/OLVEIVPB2JCrJDM3VaG6oLSkWEE3Lz8vtTwnMy9VITotvyg3sURBNVkhOjMvuUghMza2VsHS9P9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 41 bytes

```lisp
(dotimes(i 95)(princ(code-char(+ i 32))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74/18jJb8kMze1WCNTwdJUU6OgKDMvWSM5PyVVNzkjsUhDWyFTwdhIEwj@/wcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 1 byte

```
γ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/19JQTFGSVlFVU1dQ1NLW0dXT9/A0MjYxNTM3MLSytrG1s7ewdHJ2cXVzd3D08vbx9fPPyAwKDgkNCw8IjIqOiY2Lj4hMSk5JTUtPSMzKzsnNy@/oLCouKS0rLyisqq6prZO6f///7plOQA)

No builtin, 7 bytes:

```
⪫…· ¦~ω
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98rPzNPwzMvOae0OLMsNSgxLz1VQ0lBSUdBqU5JE0gqaf7//1@3LAcA)

#### Explanation

```
⪫     ω  Join by empty string
 …· ¦~    Inclusive range from " " to "~"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 12 bytes

```
L^,126 32rBF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/98nTsfQyEzB2KjIye3//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3UzAQ)

#### Explanation

```
L^,          Lambda returning stack cast to string (takes character code of numbers)
   126 32r   Inclusive range from 32 to 126
          BF Flatten stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
48*v
)?;>:o1+:763**
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38RCq4xL097azirfUNvK3MxYS@v/fwA)

#### Explanation

```
48*v               Push 32 and move down
                   Print character, increment, stop if greater than 126
)?;>:o1+:763**
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
žQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6L7A//8B)

No builtin, 8 bytes:

```
95Ý32+çJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f0vTwXGMj7cPLvf7/BwA)

#### Explanation

```
95Ý       Push [0..95]
   32+    Add 32 (vectorizes)
      ç   chr (vectorizes)
       J  Join by empty string
```

Comment: No built-in, 5 bytes: `žwƵQŸ`

Comment: Another: `₃Ýžw+`

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;E
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=O0U)

Or, without a built-in:

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
95odH
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=OTVvZEg)

```
95o       :Range [0,95)
   d      :Get the characters at those codepoints
    H     :After adding 32
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 14 bytes

```ruby
print *?\s..?~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6AoM69EQcs@plhPz77u/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip) `-w` `-gii` `-c127`, 19 bytes

```
aABbcC,~S
dDEefF^Gg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87ILPj/P9HRKSnZWacumCvFxTU1zS3OPf3///@65emZmf91kw2NzAE)

#### Flags:

- `-w` Don't attempt to read stdin
- `-gii` Generate incrementing bytes for input
- `-c127` Cut off execution at 127 cycles

#### Code:

This is a cat program suitable for ASCII (only handles 7 bits):

```
aABbcC
dDEefF Gg
```

And this suppresses output for values outside the range `0x20`-`0x7f`. (More accurately, it requires that at least one of the bits `0x20` or `0x40` to be true):

```
      ,~S
     F^G
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 52 bytes

```
[S S S T    S S S S S N
_Push_32][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S N
S _Duplicate][T N
S S _Print_as_character][S S S T    N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S T   T   T   T   T   T   T   N
_Push_127][T    S S T   _Subtract][N
T   T   N
_If_negative_Jump_to_Label_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgVMBBLi4gBgIObnAXE4usDCYwwkBIBEgwcn1/z8A) (with raw spaces, tabs, and new-lines).
Program stops with error: No exit defined.

**Pseudo-code:**

```
Integer c = 32
Start LOOP:
  Print c as character
  c = c + 1
  If c - 127 is negative:
    Go to next iteration of LOOP
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 27 bytes

```forth
: f 127 32 do i emit loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKRgamSsYGymk5CtkKqTmZpYo5OTnFyhY/0/7DwA)

### Explanation

```forth
127 32 do  \ loop from 32 to 126 (127 is not printable)
  i emit   \ get the index of the loop, then print it as its ascii representation
loop       \ end the loop
```

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell 5.1, 22 Bytes

```
-join[char[]](32..126)
```

Or 17 bytes if newlines are allowed and we can ditch the join.

Comment: A similar approach for PowerShell Core [Try it online - 15 bytes!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f9fNys/M09DXUFdT0@9Tl3z/38A "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 10 bytes

```
32|![,+]96
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=32%7C!%5B%2C%2B%5D96&inputs=)

## Explanation

This is reasonably simple:

```
32|            sets the top of the stack to 32
   !           disables implicit output of the top of the stack
    [  ]96     loops 96 times
     ,         prints the ASCII character of the int value on top of the stack
      +        increments the top of the stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 15 bytes

```julia
print.(' ':'~')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v6AoM69ET0NdQd1KvU5d8/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## AMD64 Bare Metal, 512 bytes

```
mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, 0x20
for_1:
int 0x10
add al, 1
cmp al, 0x7f
je for_1_end
jmp for_1
for_1_end:
jmp $
times 510-($-$$) db 0
db 0x55
db 0xaa
```

```sh
nasm asciiprintable.asm -f bin
qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw,file=asciiprintable
```

[image: QEMU window with characters from 0x20 to 0x7e]

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/) builtins only, 25 bytes

Using "builtins only" to avoid competing with the [`jot` solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85101/15940) (18 bytes).

[25 bytes: try it online](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIVFBozpGQU@vrlYzNTkjX0E3T0El8f9/AA)

```zsh
for a ({\ ..~})echo -n $a
```

---

[32 bytes: try it online](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIVFBo9rYSE/P0MisVjM1OSNfQTdPQaVaQ1kzsfb/fwA)

```zsh
for a ({32..126})echo -n ${(#)a}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [q](https://code.kx.com/home/), 13 bytes

```
10h$32+til 95
```

## k, 10 bytes

```
10h$32+!95
```

Generate 32, 33, ..., 126, 127 and convert these to their ASCII character representations.

Answer (score 1):

## GolfScript, <strike>15</strike> 14 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Steffan*

```
95,{[32+]''+}/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/39JUpzra2Eg7Vl1du1b//38A)

### Explanation

```
     {...}/ # for each item in
95,         # 0-95
      [32+] # add 32 to that number and put it in an array
      ''+   # output that value as ascii
```

Comment: -1 byte: `95,{[32+]''+}/`

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 38 bytes

```lua
for i=32,126 do print(('').char(i))end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/Lb9IIdPW2EjH0MhMISVfoaAoM69EQ0NdXVMvOSOxSCNTUzM1L@X/fwA)

or, if newlines are not allowed, 41 bytes:

```lua
for i=32,126 do io.write(('').char(i))end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/Lb9IIdPW2EjH0MhMISVfITNfr7wosyRVQ0NdXVMvOSOxSCNTUzM1L@X/fwA)

Comment: I think you've misread the question. The output is supposed to be all the printable ASCII characters, not the program.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I meant to post this on [Print every character your program doesn't have](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12368/print-every-character-your-program-doesnt-have?page=1&tab=modifieddesc#tab-top). Will correct this in a second

Comment: This has been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 25 bytes

```
()=>' 'to'~'foreach print
```

Anonymous function with no args which prints given range

See it online: https://ideone.com/fX2rwf

Answer (score 0):

### Lua - 41 bytes

```
for i=32,127 do io.write(("").char(i))end
```

Comment: You also have to print #127. Not collecting everything in a variable seems to be shorter: `for i=32,127 do io.write(("").char(i))end`

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 21 bytes

```perl
print map{chr}32..127
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvRCE3saA6OaOo1thIT8/QyPz/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [2sable](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable), 8 bytes

```
95Ý32+çJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MypOTMpJ/f/f0vTwXGMj7cPLvf7/BwA)

Same as for 05AB1E

#### Explanation

```
95Ý       Push [0..95]
   32+    Add 32 (vectorizes)
      ç   chr (vectorizes)
       J  Join by empty string
```

Answer (score 0):

## [3var](https://esolangs.org/wiki/3var), 20 bytes

```
iiss+<+<>+<+<kkF[Pi]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##My5LLPr/PzOzuFjbRtvGDkRkZ7tFB2TG/v8PAA)

#### Explanation

```
iiss                 Increment A twice, square A twice (set a to 16)
    +                Add A to B (set R to 16)
     <               Set B to R
      +<>            Add A and B (16 + 16 = 32), store to A and B
         +<+<        Add 32 to B twice more (B = 96)
             kk      Decrement B twice (B = 94)
               F[  ] Do B times
                 Pi  Print A as character and increment A
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 12 bytes

```
:95r:32+♂┌εj
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9/K0rTIythI@9HMpkdTes5tzfr/HwA)

#### Explanation

```
:95r          Push [0 .. 95]
    :32+      Add 32
        ♂┌    Map chr over TOS
          εj  Join by empty string
```

Answer (score 0):

**VBA (Excel), 28 bytes**

using immediate window.

`for i=32to 126:?chr(i);:next`

Answer (score 0):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), <s>80</s> <s>68</s> <s>67</s> <s>62</s> 45 bytes

```
?-between(32,126,I),writef('%n',[I]),1=0;1=1.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/3143KbWkPDU1T8PYSMfQyEzHU1OnvCizJDVNQ101T10n2jNWU8fQ1sDa0NZQ7/9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift 4](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 57 bytes

```swift
for i in 32...126{print(UnicodeScalar(i)!,terminator:"")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f8/Lb9IIVMhM0/B2EhPT8/QyKy6oCgzr0QjNC8zOT8lNTg5MSexSCNTU1GnJLUoNzMvsSS/yEpJSbP2/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 2 bytes

```
Vp
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=Vp&i=&a=1)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
ØṖ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjIc7p/3/DwA)

Yep, it's included, but here's an answer without the builtin:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
95Ḷ+32Ọ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/S9OGObdrGRg939/z/DwA)

```
95Ḷ        create lowered range, from 0 to 94 inclusive
   +32     add 32 to every element in the range
      Ọ    cast the entire list to characters and implicitly print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de)/VBA, 29 bytes

An anonymous function that takes no input and outputs to the console.

Note that the VBA answer could be 1 byte shorter by using `Chr` instead of `Chr$`.

```vb
For i=32To 126:?Chr$(i);:Next
```

Yabasic: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3y2/SCHT1tgoxF/B0MjMyt45o0hFI1PT2sovtaLk/38A)

VBA:      There is no TIO for VBA :(

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 47 bytes

```javascript
for(i=31;++i<127;)alert(String.fromCharCode(i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@Yk1pUYpucn1ecn5Oql5Of/j8tv0gj09bY0FpbO9PG0MjcWhOsRiO4pCgzL10vrSg/1zkjscgZqFsjU1Pz/38A)

Comment: I'm pretty sure Node.js doesn't have `alert`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-93](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befunge), 18 bytes

```
 g:"~"`#@_:,1+00p#
```

You can [try it here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html). The leading space is important!

```
                     The current character to be printed/checked, starts loop with a space
  g                  Push character from (0|0) onto stack(using the implicit 0s on the empty stack)
   :"~"`#@_          Check whether the char on (0|0) is over ~, if yes then end
           :,1+00p   Duplicate current char for output and incrementation
                  #  Since the code is a torus, it would continue at (0|0) so we skip it, since it could break the code.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python - 41 bytes

```python
for i in range(32, 127, 1):
 print(chr(i))
```

Python has a built-in ASCII function, so we can use that and print all 95 characters in a loop, one at a time.

#### No newlines - 50 bytes

```python
for i in range(32, 127, 1):
 x = x + chr(i)
print(x)
```

This is *just in case* newlines aren't allowed, so this entry still gets in.

Answer (score 0):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 32 bytes

```
4a5m6m6a2x1v1x1f1a1o3x1v1l0x4d1f
```

[Try it online!](https://sporeball.dev/naz/?code=4a5m6m6a2x1v1x1f1a1o3x1v1l0x4d1f&input=&n=false)

**Explanation** (with `0x` instructions removed)

```
4a5m6m6a2x1v   # Set variable 1 equal to 126
1x1f           # Function 1
    1a1o       # Add 1 to the register, then output
        3x1v1l # Goto the start of the function if the register is less than variable 1
4d             # Integer divide by 4, setting the register to a value of 31
1f             # Call function 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), 17 bytes (filename) + 0 bytes (content) = 17 bytes.

- Filename (some unprintables are escaped): `~.z.c\001.-.c\037.a.s.p`
- Content: empty.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVltU9u6Ev6eXyFEiO0EJ7ZJW8ARPRwKp52h0IH2zrm3SRljK8HTxPbYTshr/3rvSrIdOy/00MvMnYHYXq12n12tVivJsaKHn7Y/CNw@lRU5ojFS6dAcDqzoO9I0wzDpOPDDGF2e3Z1eXpIzU44nAUU9Gtu@161U@BcIGFieo5w0HDpqeMN@HxknFb1SSTp/Ov38nuCynPAhNUgF8CalPGOP2vFCvKgLnKr9cvXh77vbz@@IoWkHKfHT9e2Hvy//fXd2fXNzfvaZ6KZtRRTh8uzP09v3d/86v7n9cH11XJssMHI9JE8UxA3zUeBH7thkH7U/TZNGll1Ku/5nS086GPatmKLogfXzgxjeHv3QiYK@G5tW37UipPaQVJ7pNVz@Ay8kIrGnZF59ubw8@/iOHAtNKUgZcTc7w8FgYkYPbjc2s2/EeiZEaj/4qLyrIEVg0RUUhK4Xd9Fe1G57DLO2u1ttLI7Rpz5lsofw79FHGgoPqWxcrdi97zP0tN@vM7e6MdITQHRk9RHeQV2rH1E8n89eTsHCpGHoh2NZ2S60bCTsZcZf4JK6Q8@OXd9D1j2MuDyIesqMcyDMBSMdYQRULkDWFHOR9YDIiuSQxvu2MnO7sns/7HZpSAjGyqzrhzbt9ofRg6yYwENk4I5pOIdH3/UoSrgVE3pCe4toCjyGoYfgYdp9P6JJF1Bpk4Sdcds7PzACFak@jM0FBb/OouG9jFG9Wsb7GAMokxO@fkOdKuKkTOfC8ft9K9SIbSZKwTGlzLCBNblPwc/4M4ppUKsx7dnnCeGvVpz6i3@aWTvRzMXSV3l/bOfP2N3ovm9532XwbALQJuTAmM/loxaxKxW7RfQDsOPP878@XM3oIIgnBPMHFhIJ5g9ckJ9aDR7jk0oGn0SxZX/fx8dYydEid0oTWghpRGY/EaWOYg4s1@NRIJmxb0UDsgwgeFqBG1t92ctQy69ftYhXqXgtcqQpb2WvdmAox17BUnvg5Ht4YOiBApayl9fpy5vkpZk2NV@xl6NMvK4Z8NwhR6/F4zDh0zXGCJNaO8pYDcGq6wfJ803mSvAADa0@c1EQ0hH31SKjyukLi/G3Ze1YLmswPTBK6CBG2LP0RVlTlEpFyCKOH7OZknBDHH8T0cl/yxDTPGLzRBG4mfhl5x@NekPhgYT7SwDmQsxuvGe3PbxfgGHmbFvMBKIyBN351bvZr@Xy8X78TiThJ7fn@SG9c6jlQGJ6gODyaBSzuGFxXAZbsYWZ2IwMEzxNLHWLLWQ0QjDLQAqqP@6j@hj@J/sIMk59iufYtiC7nVQMbCaddlE08WJrjERaCkK/F1qDZR5MFamquQ5usUoi@syj45hB/dH49vVxPJl2yo1ZKgTm@qKsgxF9POuJNKKpR50ajAafMF9dR8wSeOl0SMXMPqAnTBvRhw0e5FiEk1RUr7PRVIRFZeYygQD0BFg4B4NDZJdk4lTddE/AAFdVU/dlANyO6dA@ZUtmjrTI@kI3nNfhpzoQgoGRo@lSjXKirYkHBlVX1nWk9CVG1VwUFHmpoo1qvAFZk8UCZdDKMDRfmd6gSsD4hR@R5mENiMCwp0MUMweBCEFpMIo3OAFf5knKbLUbisTEkNsYlr02VvwomSsI3p5voovTYM7bx@xIkuwOAU1YWUbLtEOSJpOtVmwI@AKqIHAKixKENjKzJtZhAwv4h1HTtM4UckIhGPOo7/JRZpp82U57C7wZKrYgi5Kgjet3x5DdoSakdkwddH59AZzM1nSZSmRweYlRv@4PVWnsekMKkzOHAhL8LOpBpfkMJPchtb6viHnFxai/Kad52EoHoFJJXlqvDhNoCV9emOsFwxh5fgxvMe3RkMl7SpIzSslq81BExLo8N1oVmRu4pVUCz1OwmbZRVddq8lJpfgQSizbltqhXdUbm1pCy8az0xGQvxOv2@cXybUFslM2vLcnq@VN2lAZ/YcaKfAsJtsWSRTRtGBDZtRogfyT5tJp7L9rhCrVrJBI9rgDopgCgDIC5A9VUoZmmzfnyky0cAfDW9BXu8Mkcy4hxsObw4hwI2RxwaBfKcYcVqGzOshhb7cUTK68DlWocKCtWPa7mlAL8jegeHfJbqwwIg65ZwBdxjJ@JgxjKbHxPduRVla0CwQCvbQW3iW4UQBODqR7fK2gT5slvYJ5swnzy8pgnWzBPl1XEM1BP78kaaEJeHvV0C2orRV0kx0/OogdqBeQF6qFBTguTuUP4Vi2XHeWl4g5hLE@kRgcy7rvrz@8@np7dXL8/vzk3Syt1Ni@JtbUyWM9LqW23nI3XqqNrL@EH9Xk61Y114ipXixV3KzReOj4f387z8FVfwiflp3WO9LVJYo6M306fI70KvfOLQPkYTWnoq447ciPYkK8tAKCRjIyTkf6WLQMjozHSlWP@qjdGxupqsPd/NmfvuebsLc3ZK5iTbIvTebWT279e@bB/DUMaBb7nuF4PwYaWrZ8vso@FnTY/kJRyx1GuByXAPkIsMyRpiWcQM7/Xk5Yne@zwT@eHf3juO0g99ZA6iof6PA6RehYhTTcOmq9evzk8QtLXtlftSPNeSANUn8MWH1hhSxGT5msQww95MCfjsrxywMhPBPA8gvJBahRSUsNulxDKKjhxtmNiScGJcWAlq4L4oVTMzgzS0@EENj@Irda/di86VQVxVh0Vj3dXWel5wkrXWFl/9kMFswYpQ@TIDXzrZ8DQYDzXj9wnUaNebeT3bNtODBrSXF4Z9LRGnEkALs68pqwBTm1KTcpO22PUaqkSq/EfnFBanm4mFeX@k8G0LIsFFTqIBMxL47VaWDTzOjm/bpUS7aX/yZcvGJP5yiVvHt@7M9Pa@W12YlXKouqdTmFPkDIv28HohLjhZIa3LPhv2pop59R0mpjLebIV6D9DWIS26bRoDYkYtG4cSiIlacrPXZZ4HBrWUTCmA7vOL3fcaFAv7YInIQSTlnGhJX6gE2SFFHVDf8DbC80D33G7brLz@PzhmtHg7yGOg@i40ei58cPwvm77g8Zf79XPgUUvrMcp9RoFQaVd6FKgsD3z2ZlWL5Uurk4/npNlhEg/6tO63dY0va6y58GbulWP6gE4u3R7/eXm7JxI0s98pHIJeP5oI9XmSbwQx6LP1mbeeRNTSU4COrk/YBDFFZQsw396X3d689fdx9O/@f0ems8RZzE02LerR0jhl1UgQ1yREMwGCKme/uuphVaylEpZovqGqo2GlHygahk@uPz05J@B/MpM4BePQ0aGQe1UKkAM14gzlMKInSZSr5pMVJ5JIHNyyKAuYvdichBBRx8FEJ40dgd0P7CD4f4ompqOFVMlb1/z16kjttw@uAU1DZERdLddUg29@aZ5ePC6eVhiGbot19uzw/airZQbbR1ScTI8FtGQNLNq2SG5WM4sdha@AO@La1Z2n5uFyjIqoD0dM0ks9Abq@zBGXUBEHUmZo1IxvQ2scZ96/yAY5vPNoSDmKMFpuHOimJ6kLbEPAALzmmBJVCQoOcu/vrlldwKXFyQ9JMVtD@omZwhfvTt/GAfDmB2iN77xkC03@LlhoZXoSnKrxRWiy4u17qKsanzj7lgX8cv@4tT8IF9SiezYhOxIri5EXhRSri9uUdnNsyaHvZcXayVZF2Ge6PaG7MoElY3krtRgYNW34uBf2LxTRJwoE45fwaunVzEIt9t7Pt7PzvtnyRXNY9w9ZsuWx9ryqLj6g4OsBN3uJgjFefSA1OjnfwE)

### With comments

```
XX.z
.a~.zXX.z # push 127; while size<2 || (pop!=pop); do
  .a.cXX.z # dup
  .a\001.-XX.z # push 1; push abs(pop-pop) iff size>=2
  .a.cXX.z # dup
.a\037.aXX.z # push 31; done
.a.s.pXX.z # pop (* to remove 31 *); while size>0; do printf "%c", pop; done
.a
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 18 bytes

```
32 126 [a,b] write
```

Works in any modern version of Factor that supports printing non-string sequences directly. (i.e. not TIO.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/), 27 bytes

```kotlin
(' '..'~').joinToString("")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@59WmqeQm5iZp6GpUF1QlJlXkpOn8V9DXUFdT0@9Tl1TLys/My8kP7gEKJWuoaSk@V@z9j8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 23 bytes

```
;=a 31W>127=a+1aO+Aa"\"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVhpc9u2Fv3eX0GzqUWINC25nXYimfYkrvMm8xo5L3abaSUlAkFIYkMRChfbqcT@9b57wQ3U5jQfMiJwcDecu8B/0nsas8hfJieh8Pg/LKBxrP039Gfz5DqKRKTxx4SHXqzJr1WWA97SKObNfeVMiXqXhom/eBp3m0ScLlZMhHESpSwRkUHJKpn7sR2LNGLcoRns@Mv3cz/h8ZIybhT7C5qwuXH6wRiOxqPhKIb1rDc2198OP4zCcdsYhetnhLRPSbbk/BPsRjxJo1BThA874/U6TIMgy4W5FnM6ZBXwRKOOa/NHzgwFTvqFCDziOA69xB89FeIov@04dcF2g4IaO@DhLJkTiw7ZmGSJAMf9cLbTqiyT4dDufn97fesMx/08VL/RIOWrOKGJz7Ql3oLhkpVrb4WnP4Uo3tMIfOj06bkUU@jvU9PM/WOOXB/SsV3K6vtTg5HCHpYpvmZRGsqwR@JBC/lDzojM424627G@xzspxK43ATdIFy6P9uDKTcC9FCLgNNwDrHazglW/QDAiGlTEy0O3QbI4XaJ0S4r66NGEAtdyRxUlO5wpvutzuzwpvpugLTfKBRXGPwdoXoGgmg9W05BxMc29Vtw4PlaMBz7mv8oooPAqBEVItvhTcr3OprtXYzJ8cfLHuH1qdSvK0@NjvGCUaeh3OmojmZculpUzk9KZZzI/MzLJgmReu3JU23p8TBvXNlNxmoo7agKznMzLNJ4buEr6eapcD357/e5m8OZ6cOessiJhXns8TDY48JT7Q3ry18cx/t85ef4RQrAZACkUjM0OsclHELCpGR951J/6gMtDlOMwUGCuPwtRjuLJsMaMK2rmBu9BYQbfC9/TOkd4P6Xl/TpB1bpsTH4NP4XiIdT8yjKt1TCtNWnGXLpAyvgq0f1aeo08czukENAiXSjZJFWxUXOKep7ClfJ8zRmTKqWDZFCDD8JPmvBFGhyEt5twz79Xvay38CYal1CKekOTuQ28CZki9RT83ndJ@hUNQ5FooAruRHO/aH/xSOhgqvD@pe5a4Xf0SX0gPg2Eom8pHg7rq8Wv10cGPe@Qr3K@3f4K7/njUoRIUppwaZCWCKiNIZ8B3@65BsbxCIwM9lSSc/Xe9tabiwaqQfya9gNoiId5r1TviviDoqSSnPMopFFCygqC7XYjB3QEG0Q/1BmkvML5J0LJxALM5PKIrVfB@Jen1ODgWhkdaI5PBgcp5DpU6Tl6a0xgjotHt@P2JRl1T60zSSuMBjDLVYkEGnBYyYcYaufDHYL1FrYltl639Bb@ILVL9dCKRQ@sWvghMMnTPqcCCMVDJlJc5l5Pe7ai2WRXS5f2N/PI6nbIet3ZqFnFgHCoZqETkwJQKNwuPQiqddkRX3IKvUetQE8wvhq1DjK@QqmXCotFd4VT1Lv9ErIezZyIf079iBv6NNaJtcIRWW65yhab@4H3cRkJxmNEvfp1cHX3@mZwW/fmV1ADDrVmhSX5BcNkXokZukqnkzetzKp9hVeXPZl15tompzljOM7TOB/jhwfzsXfOytnYK2fjqSMtsktTUNnRdA@d3vjQu8OZRqNZusCB49nKM7uZBkq0KXoJHdXFRtrneWCnJFPuGANhMMu1@MZIAUtsY6xAcQ7Nf4d0wR03/w2qY4dtz67ygGHbdoWqKktexXXUnvgiNHSzklqFx9XKkVMepaajW5puunYuo@ripr5Vm27cPzlLbD@W/LVgXMqmhSot4jM/Trh0kawgtF3sVeUDaeMtYegDMElbpDDkuZCoj5QlwRcNeoHG5jSCL5hZAhHOoCb1a4LQseMqGiEwVedSr7ZIMniBGq6SB0StPfUYlb83@jtpoA@Edo@SoVCmgYe2ShXeEdRKJasw4MSqQqC/1S2DOBfFk0zXLdd5mU6nPLJpEAhmwADuCQwSNTrAiA5M5BZQ3oUnJXHB8E99ZoKrD5Bx3OhCF5Y78iVnY2699yHx9VGoE8IcZseBDy/EjqWd1JN9WWkYyVTL3uWWNVr3NBDg6w9nz394/uNPZ89/bMvViIaeWGDY1PPXukWdCwwZbYS2hrRetBBSJXoe3sIqV@1uYMBlaWYuyZ5GYnEFDLgSHgyaxduJ9Epz1eu0WYF7keDMphr5UhpJ1aWrfKl4XMr/1e2J3K76UNO5PY7q/5OHioJo80d/s4or2KNKgXxrNR9ADeQvFRI9Vg0pk0lF/4zcuqjGt0awS8vixBNpYj9E0LhBYJ7nxKKNmN00BdVaC2n6aCSfhwXZgGmXe@SXbAQI6e3ETLA3fjMhVjUzqZaYQFEsIvV1YaMtfGs4f7KFxHfBLmR7C4l9eRfydAspXwM7kN9tyxS77fywhZRT9w7keYWsqFIewYmgOqKeudh/ZrbvzOX@M1jyd545rs4YtMzrxt9pLotjvUbmrZ88Rnvudkb2lWP5rrUrYI4Ca9QWfNKu16BSed43E5naxfvcdSr9bkP4@0r4Crtnv5G0fbKRbjvJ/DoXAU3fuaA7g8W2ff@PckgGrbbbchuPNAvLv/JZVjBa/pUShazXut6M2m2hwJMqykNPqPIcb1tzBS5bPY71l9SEqbI0ATocMZlZm2R62IvrhvF3S614zac74CA6ZRWBieV@eAad8B/413eo9n33/UX37CeHml16Y76g@kj/Pw)

Unminified:

```
; = a 31
: WHILE (> 127 (= a (+ 1 a)))
    : OUTPUT (+ (ASCII a) "\")
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 7 bytes

```
' '~R&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/19dQb0uSC3//38A)

```
' '~     - push first (" ") and last ("~") printable characters
    R    - generate a rage of codepoints
     &o  - print the stack as characters
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), 9 bytes

```
00000000: 3e 20 06 5f ff 3c 10 fc 76                     > ._.<..v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q7IwSM/PSfv/3wAKrBSMUxWMDBQMzBRM0xTS0hSMkxUMDRTSkhXMzRSwATsFvXg9Gz29sv//AQ)

Assembler source (z80asm):

```clojure
start:
    ; start at space
    ld      a, ' '
    ; loop counter 
    ; I could also cp 0x7f; jr nz, .loop but this is faster to TOTALLY make up for below
    ld      b, 0x7F - ' '
.loop:
    ; Call 0x38, then nop slide to 0x8000 to print A to stdout
    ; only has a 130842 cycle overhead, which is worth the 2 bytes it saves
    rst     0x38
    ; set A to the next char
    inc     a
    ; Decrement b, then loop if non-zero
    djnz    .loop
    ; Exit
    halt
```

Pretty straightforward loop approach.

Answer (score 0):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (v2), 23 bytes

```
;;=s@W>95s=s+sA+32sO^sN
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyI7Oz1zQFc+OTVzPXMrc0ErMzJzT15zTiIsIiIsIjIuMCJd)

Another Alternative is

```
;=a@W>95=a+1aO+A+31a"\"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pascal, 66 B

This program *requires* to be run on a processor using the ASCII character set (or a binary-compatible superset).
The output will look quite different for instance on an IBM mainframe using EBCDIC.

```pascal
program p(output);var c:char;begin for c:=' 'to'~'do write(c)end.
```

Note, in Pascal `for`-loop limits are *inclusive*.
During the final iteration `c` assumes the specified value `'~'`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 14 bytes

```
' w.oh.'~h-$K@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/19doVwvP0NPvS5DV8Xb4f9/AA)

### Explanation

```
' w.oh.'~h-$K@   Full program
'                Adds 32 (space) on the stack
  w        $K@   Repeat until...
      .'~h-      ...we reach 126 (~)
   .oh           Print and increase the current character
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 45 bytes

```go
func(){for i:=32;i<127;i++{print(string(i))}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BloLE5OzE9FSF3MTMPK6yxCKFNAXbpaUlaboWN3XTSvOSNTSr0_KLFDKtbI2NrDNtDI3MrTO1tasLijLzSjSKS4BUukampmZtLVRTF0gT2DQNTYVqrjQNTS6w2pw8JJaSgmKMkrKKqpq6hqaWto6unr6BoZGxiamZuYWllbWNrZ29g6OTs4urm7uHp5e3j6-ff0BgUHBIaFh4RGRUdExMbFx8QmJSckpqWnpGZlZ2Tm5efkFhUXFJaVl5RWVVdU1tnZImF9RFCxZAaAA)

Prints to STDERR.

Answer (score 0):

## [International Phonetic Esoteric Language](https://esolangs.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Esoteric_Language), 21 bytes

```forth
{3j}{w}ɑeχue1søɒ
```

### Ungolfed

```forth
{3j}{w}   ( loop bounds: 32 w <= e < 127 3j )
ɑ         ( loop )
 e        ( push index )
  χ       ( ord index )
   u      ( pop-output without newline )
    e1sø  ( increment index )
        ɒ ( end loop )
```